# Proof of 'No natural number whose multiplication of digits is equal to 3570'

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

I have to prove that there is no natural number whose multiplication of digits is equal to $3570$

What would be the proper mathematical solution to this question?

Comment: Hint : $17$ is a prime factor of $3570$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose there were a natural number that satisfies this. Any natural number has the base 10 digit form $x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}$ where we understand each $x_{j}$ to be a digit (not a product!). In particular $1 \leq x_{1} \leq 9$ and is an integer, and for $2 \leq j \leq n$, $0 \leq x_{j} \leq 9$ and is also an integer.
Then we would have
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}=3570=2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 17.
$$

17 is a prime and hence on the left hand side of the above one would need an $x_{j}$ to be a multiple of 17 for the equation to hold. But every multiple of 17 is two digits or more which contradicts the definition of our $x_{j}$'s. Hence we have the result.

Comment: All integer having a prime factor of two or more digits satisfies the property.